# "No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression"

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch

I try to handle exception but a warning occurs. "No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression"

```
 do{
   var folderID = getFolder()?
   }catch{
 }
```

Comment: I think you meant `try getFolder()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning clearly states that `getFolder()` does **not** `throw`. To get rid of the warning remove the `do - catch` block

```
let folderID = getFolder()
```

Note:

In Swift you cannot catch arbitrary exceptions like in Objective-C.
A `do - catch` block catches only `Error`s thrown by methods marked with the `throws` keyword.